# Android layout: one widget scrollable and two fixed at bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, scrollable

I have been asking here or the problems I'm having with this layout for weeks, so this time I'll show a picture of what I need:

[image]

I want an EditText and a Button at the **bottom of the screen always** (and when keyboard show up, **they must appear over the keyboard, not stay under the keyboard**). The rest of the free screen must be fot an scrollable TextView.

EDIT: this is the code right now, following Romain indications. Everything works as expected but the scroll. TextView must be scrollable and it is not. How to fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/consola"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom">

        <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:text="Conectar"
            android:id="@+id/boton"
            android:label="@string/enviar_string"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution by myself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView   
android:id="@+id/scroller"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1.0">  

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/consola"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</ScrollView>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="bottom">

    <Button
        android:text="Conectar"
        android:id="@+id/boton"
        android:label="@string/enviar_string"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your layout is too complicated, here is an abridged version of what you should be doing:

```
LinearLayout width=fill_parent height=fill_parent orientation=vertical
    TextView width=fill_parent height=0dip layout_weight=1.0
    EditText width=fill_parent height=wrap_content
    Button width=fill_parent height=wrap_content
```

The layout_weight on the TextView is the key: it tells the parent LinearLayout that you want to give this TextView all the remaining empty space (it's also why the height is set to 0dip.)

Comment: Ok, I have also surrounded EditText and Button with a second LinearLayout to get them to bottom setting gravity. But now I want this same linear layout containing both widgets to stay always on top of the keyboard when showing. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Set [`isScrollContainer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aisScrollContainer) to true on the TextView allowing it to resize if a softkeyboard needs to be displayed. Add android:windowSoftInputMode="[adjustResize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)" to your activity in your manifest.

[Some slightly outdated documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html)